# I got Flutter Build time and runtime error - Execution failed for task ':background_locator:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: flutter

I got Flutter Build time and runtime error - Execution failed for task ':background_locator:compileDebugKotlin'.

when i try to run the app i got error as below, please help me.
[image]

Please can anyone help me to how i solve this problem.

below is my flutter doctor -v output.
PS D:_**_**> flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at D:\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (8 days ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
    • Engine revision caaafc5604
    • Dart version 2.17.1
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Dev_Flutter\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.0)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32210.238
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Dev_Flutter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.40.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • CPH2127 (mobile)  • 1cb8d2b1 • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows  • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 101.0.4951.67
    • Edge (web)        • edge     • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 101.0.1210.39

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Using Flutter 3.0.x ? https://github.com/rekabhq/background_locator/issues/333

Answer (score 0):

Try This command in your project directory:

**Flutter Pub Upgrade**

There may be an inconsistency between your imported package and the flutter version you're using. this command will upgrade your packages to the latest feasible version.

Also, Please Provide your Flutter doctor output which is helpful to find a solution.

Comment: okay i will update the question put the flutter doctor output.

Comment: as Dabbel mentioned in a comment under your question,
Seems like the package has issues on Flutter 3
The issue is reported here: github.com/rekabhq/background_locator/issues/333